# Program done in netbeans and works fine but when cut and pasted to notepad and then compiled will not work properly

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd

I created a program in netbeans and all the options in the program works but when I take the code and pasted in notepad and then compile it at the cmd some options work and some don't, why is that?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
You should create at least 2 Java classes – Titanic and TestTitanic
 */
public class TestTitanic{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //Use command line arguments to send in the name of the Titanic file
        String fileName = args[0];
        Titanic titanic = new Titanic(fileName);
        //The application should keep track of the elapsed time (in seconds) 
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //A user-friendly and well-organized menu s
        String choices[] =
        {"Total number of passengers on the Titanic",
            "Total number of passengers who perished on the Titanic",
            "Total number of Passengers who survived the sinking of the Titanic",
            "Number of passengers who survived the sinking of the Titanic as a function of the passenger class (e.g. 1,2,3)",
            "Number of passengers who survived the sinking of the Titanic as a function of the passenger gender (e.g., male, female)",
            "A list of the names of passengers who paid greater than $200 for their tickets",
            "A list of the names of passengers who were less than 10 years old who survived",
            "A list of the names of passengers who were less than 10 years old who perished ",
            "The count of the number of passengers as a function of the first letter of their last name. (e.g., A: 13, B:33 …)", "Exit"};
        int choice = menuChoice(choices);
        while (choice != 10) {
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Total number of passengers on the Titanic: " + titanic.getTotalPassengers());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Total number of passengers who perished on the Titanic: " + titanic.getTotalNumberofPerishedPassengers());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Total number of passengers who survived : " + titanic.getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengers());
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.print("Enter class (e.g. 1,2,3): ");
                    int cls = getIntInRange(1, 3);
                    System.out.println(cls + " class number of passengers who survived: " + titanic.getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengersByClass(cls));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.print("Enter gender (e.g., male, female): ");
                    String gender = getString();
                    System.out.println("Number of " + gender + " passengers who survived: " + titanic.getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengersByGender(gender));
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.print("Names of passengers who paid greater than $200 for their tickets: ");
                    System.out.println(titanic.getNamesPaidFare(200));
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.print("Names of passengers who were less than 10 years old who survived: ");
                    System.out.println(titanic.getSurvivedNamesLessGivenAge(10));
                    break;
                case 8:
                    System.out.print("Names of passengers who were less than 10 years old who perished: ");
                    System.out.println(titanic.getPerishedNamesLessGivenAge(10));
                    break;
                case 9:
                    System.out.print("Enter the letter: ");
                    char ch = getString().charAt(0);
                    System.out.println("Count: " + titanic.getCountByFirstLetterOfFirstName(ch));
                    break;
            }
            choice = menuChoice(choices);
        }

        //The application should keep track of the elapsed time (in seconds) 
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
        /**
         * After the program is exited, the application should provide a prompt
         * thanking the user for trying the Titanic program and providing the
         * total time elapsed.
         */
        System.out.println("Thank you for trying the Titanic program");
        System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + elapsedTime);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to get String from user
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static String getString() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        return input.nextLine();
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to get user input in range
     *
     * @param low
     * @param high
     * @return
     */
    public static int getIntInRange(int low, int high) {
        int num = 0;
        do {
            num = getInt();
            if (num < low || num > high) {
                System.out.println("Enter number between " + low + " and " + high);
            }
        } while (num < low || num > high);
        return num;
    }

    /**
     *
     * method to display organized menu to user
     *
     * @param choices
     * @return
     */
    public static int menuChoice(String choices[]) {
        int choice = 0;
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + choices[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("Enter choice (1-" + choices.length + "): ");
        choice = getIntInRange(1, choices.length);
        return choice;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to get int from user
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static int getInt() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = -1;
        boolean good;
        do {
            good = true;
            try{
                num = input.nextInt();
            }

            catch(Exception e) {
                good = false;
                input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter numeric value: ");
            }
        } while (!good);
        return num;
    }
}
```

Here is the other code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
// java class Titanic
public class Titanic{

    int maxPassengers = 10000;
    int actualPassengers = 0;
    //B. Use a 2D array to store the Titanic data. 
    String[][] data = new String[maxPassengers][6];

    /**
     * Constructor to read file and set 2D array to store the Titanic data
     */
    Titanic(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
            //line has tab delimeted data
            data[actualPassengers++] = fileReader.nextLine().split("\t");

        }
        fileReader.close();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Total number of passengers on the Titanic
     */
    public int getTotalPassengers() {
        return actualPassengers;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Total number of passengers who perished on the Titanic
     */
    public int getTotalNumberofPerishedPassengers() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {

            int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
            //Survived (1=yes, 0=no)
            if (status == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Total number of Passengers who survived the sinking of the
     * Titanic
     */
    public int getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengers() {
        return getTotalPassengers() - getTotalNumberofPerishedPassengers();
    }

    /**
     * Number of passengers who survived the sinking of the Titanic as a
     * function of the passenger class (e.g. 1,2,3)
     *
     * @param cls
     * @return
     */
    public int getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengersByClass(int cls) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
            int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
            int clazz = Integer.parseInt(data[i][0]);
            //Survived (1=yes, 0=no)
            if (status == 1 && clazz == cls) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Number of passengers who survived the sinking of the Titanic as a
     * function of the passenger gender (e.g., male, female)
     *
     * @param gender
     * @return
     */
    public int getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengersByGender(String gender) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
            int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
            //Survived (1=yes, 0=no)
            if (status == 1 && gender.equalsIgnoreCase(data[i][3])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param fair
     * @return A list of the names of passengers who paid greater than given
     * fair for their tickets
     */
    public String getNamesPaidFare(double fair) {
        String name = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
            if (data[i].length >= 6) {
                double pfair = Double.parseDouble(data[i][5]);
                if (pfair > fair) {
                    name += "\n" + data[i][2];
                }
            }
        }
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * G. A list of the names of passengers who were less than 10 years old who
     * survived the sinking of the Titanic
     *
     * @param age
     * @return
     */
    public String getSurvivedNamesLessGivenAge(int age) {
        String name = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
            if (data[i].length >= 6 && data[i][4].length() > 0) {
                int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
                double pAge = Double.parseDouble(data[i][4]);
                //Survived (1=yes, 0=no)
                if (status == 1 && pAge < age) {
                    name += "\n" + data[i][2];
                }
            }
        }
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * H. A list of the names of passengers who were less than 10 years old who
     * perished on the Titanic
     *
     * @param age
     * @return
     */
    public String getPerishedNamesLessGivenAge(int age) {
        String name = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
            if (data[i].length >= 6 && data[i][4].length() > 0) {
                int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
                double pAge = Double.parseDouble(data[i][4]);
                //Survived (1=yes, 0=no)
                if (status == 0 && pAge < age) {
                    name += "\n" + data[i][2];
                }
            }
        }
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * The count of the number of passengers as a function of the first letter
     * of their last name. (e.g., A: 13, B:33 …)
     *
     * @param ch
     * @return
     */
    public int getCountByFirstLetterOfFirstName(char ch) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
            char pChar = data[i][2].charAt(0);

            if (Character.toUpperCase(ch) == Character.toUpperCase(pChar)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

here is the stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1 at Titanic.getTotalNumbersofPerishedPassengers(Titanic.java:43) at TestTitanic.main(TestTitanic.java:34)

Comment: what it dint work ? I mean what you faced ?

Comment: for instance when i choose the second option it throws  an exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1 but the first item in the menu i choose it works

Comment: It is no where a problem related to netbeans or other editor. Better to debug or post the code here. **`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`** is normally thrown when you cross the limits of array while iterating over it. That means your array is of 0 size

Comment: is there any way i can email you the two .java files

Comment: Rather post your code here. Would be better to post with stacktrace. Post only part of the code which is part of exception trace.

Comment: Please add your code snippet (the part of code you think is failing) or link to some online code tool and error in the question itelf

Comment: that is what i am trying to do but the format is not working out i have done the four sapce in and also the 8 space in still not working

Comment: i have add the code any help will be great please keep in mind that the program works fine in netbeans but i need to work in cmd

Comment: Now post your stacktrace also.

Comment: what do mean stacktrace???

Comment: does anyone else have any input

Comment: i mean to say  post your logs to findout which line this error is pointing  to ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1 at Titanic.getTotalNumbersofPerishedPassengers(Titanic.java:43) at TestTitanic.main(TestTitanic.java:34)